# How to calculate coefficients, solutions etc. in quadratic function with limited inputs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, quadratic

I have a problem. I want to calculate everything in the quadratic function. equations for reference:

```
ax^2 + bx + c
a(x-p)^2 + q
```

I made 8 possible inputs in tkinter and I want my program to try and calculate everything if possible. Otherwise to return sth like not enough data.
Equations:

```
delta = b^2-4ac
p = -b/(2a)
p = (x1+x2)/2
q = -delta/(4a)
#if delta>0
x2 = (-b-sqrt(delta))/(2a)
x1 = (-b+sqrt(delta))/(2a)
#if delta=0
x0 = -b/(2a)
#if delta<0 no solutions
#a, b, c are the coefficients.
b = -2ap
c = p^2*a+q
```

Example:

```
Input:
p = 3
q = -9
x1 = 0.877868
a = 2

Output:
b = -12
c = 9
x2 = 5.12132
delta = 72
```

So, for example, I give it [x1, x2, a] and it will calculate [q, p, b, c, and delta] if possible.
Is there a function that I can give all different formulas to and it will try to calculate everything?
For now, my only idea is to brute force it in 'try' or with 'ifs', but I feel like it would take thousands of lines of code, so I won't do that.

Comment: What does "calculate everything in the quadratic function" mean? What output are you expecting? How are "p", "q", and "delta" related to "ax^2 + bx + c"?

Comment: delta is used to calculate solutions x1, x2 its equation is b^2 - 4ac
(p, q) is the Vertex p = -b/(2a) q = -delta/(4a). The outputs i expect are numbers

Comment: I'm still not quite following. Perhaps instead of the (quite unrelated) tkinter stuff in your question, edit in some example inputs and outputs..?

Comment: I'll do it then

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing, code-debugging, or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can use sympy's solve. This is my solution. I used Eq for defining equations and then solved them.

```py
def missingVariables(dictOfVariables):
    symbols = dict(a=sym('a'), b=sym('b'), c=sym('c'), p=sym('p'), q=sym('q'), x1=sym('x1'), x2=sym('x2'),
                   delta=sym('delta'))
    var = mergeDicts(symbols, dictOfVariables)

    deltaEQ = Eq((var['b'] ** 2 - 4 * var['a'] * var['c']), var['delta'])
    x1EQ = Eq(((-var['b'] - sqrt(var['delta'])) / (2 * var['a'])), var['x1'])
    x2EQ = Eq(((-var['b'] + sqrt(var['delta'])) / (2 * var['a'])), var['x2'])
    pEQ = Eq((-var['b']) / (2 * var['a']), var['p'])
    pEQ2 = Eq(((var['x1'] + var['x2']) / 2), var['p'])
    qEQ = Eq(((-var['delta']) / (4 * var['a'])), var['q'])
    bEQ = Eq((-2 * var['a'] * var['p']), var['b'])
    cEQ = Eq((var['a'] * var['p'] ** 2 + var['q']), var['c'])

    solution = solve((deltaEQ, x1EQ, x2EQ, pEQ, pEQ2, qEQ, bEQ, cEQ))
    solution = solution[0]
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in solution.items():
        try:
            new_dict[str(k)] = round(float(v), 4)
        except TypeError:
            new_dict[str(k)] = v
    return new_dict
```